# How can I find objects inside a closed polyline with Pyautocad?

Tags: python, autocad

I Need to search objects that are inside the polyline. I already can find objects and the polyline, but I can't make the script decide if it is inside or not.

Comment: You forgot to include the script you are asking about.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I included now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

````
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint, aDouble
from math import *

for object in acad.iter_objects():
    
    if object.ObjectName == 'AcDb2dPolyline':
        polygon = object
        
for block in acad.iter_objects():
    if block.ObjectName == 'AcDbBlockReference':
        
        #Here i want to test if the block is inside the polygon
            ```
````

Comment: Your existing code needs to be included in the question, not a separate answer. Please [edit] your question and insert this code there.